# Quartz.Net F# code run in script but not in main

Tags: f#, quartz.net

I have put the code on Quartz from 
http://fssnip.net/ec

into a F# source file in VS 2013. But I put the last line in to a function :

```
let start():unit=
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger) |> ignore
```

It works fine when start() is called from a script or from a main method.

However when I changed

```
type Job () =
  interface IJob with
     member x.Execute(context: IJobExecutionContext) =
     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)
```

to

```
// omit the (), so that Job is an interface
type Job =
  interface IJob with
     member x.Execute(context: IJobExecutionContext) =
     Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now)
```

calling start() still works (ie time is printed every second), and calling start() from a main method no longer works.
I expect calling start() will no longer works, no matter it is called from a script or source file.

I would be grateful if someone could explain why calling start() from a script file still works.

Shing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you omit the () in the type line, the Job type no longer has the primary constructor. It's still a class, it still implements IJob, but there's no constructor defined in the code - C# in that scenario would add a default parameterless one, F# doesn't. Omitting it doesn't make Job an interface in any way - I think you might have wanted to do this (use an object expression to define a concrete instance of the interface):

```
 let job = 
     { new IJob with
          member this.Execute ...
        }
```

Now, I don't know the details of what Quartz does when you schedule a job, but most likely it tries to create an instance of the class in order to call the interface methods - since the constructor is gone, that attempt fails (I'm surprised that it fails silently though).

This is what you're seeing when calling from the main method.

When doing the same from a FSI, however, a type like your Job type gets compiled with a default parameterless constructor. I don't know why this discrepancy between the two environments, and whether it's on purpose or a bug (I assume the latter).

You can verify it by calling `typeof<Job>.GetConstructors()` (from `System.Reflection`) on your type. The results will differ in Main and FSI.

Comment: I have added typeof<Job>.GetConstructors() in the script and in the main function.  In the script, typeof<Job> returns [|Void .ctor()|] . In the main, it returns [||].

Comment: It fails silently in a way, the job is instantiated on a different processing thread but error is logged. Not having logging enabled with error level usually leads to problems like these. I've even seen people do DB queries in constructor which might fail...